# How to Create a SwiftUI View in a VStack That Pops Out with Overlay Highlight

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

Consider the following simplified snippet

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      // Some other views here that should also be covered
      VStack {
        ForEach(0..<8) { i in
          ListElement()
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
}

struct ListElement: View {
  @State private var isFocused: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.isFocused.toggle()
    }, label: {
      Text(isFocused ? "I am focused" : "I am not focused")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(.gray)
        .background(
          isFocused ?
          Color.pink
            .opacity(0.5)
            .frame(width: 10000, height: 10000)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .onTapGesture {
              self.isFocused = false
            }
          : nil
        )
    })
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

which results in the following

[image: snippet preview]

Usually the ScrollView contains many more ListElements.
If a user taps on one ListElement, I want it to resize and show additional information which is a simple Button.
However, I also want everything but the ListElement to have a transparent overlay in order to put more emphasis on the selected ListElement and deemphasize everything else.
If a user taps anything but the selected ListElement (in this case, its background) the respective ListElement should no longer be focused.
There are a few solutions to this (such as a "Tutorial"-like View) but as far as I know none that work in ScrollViews due to being dependent on GeometryReader.

In the example code I have tried to implement this with an absurdly large `background`-modifier on each ListElement that would cover the entire screen.
It looks like this:

[image: code snippet on tap listelement]

Hooray! The VStack is visually deemphasized and the selected ListElement is clearly in focus. However, if any but the last ListElement is selected, the following happens:

[image: code snipped on tap listelement any but the last]

As you can see, the `background`-modifier does not cover any ListElement thats after the selected one hierarchically. I assume this is because of the view hierarchy in SwiftUI. Is there any way to push the currently selected ListElement to the top of the hierarchy so I can cover anything else behind it?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you have to add `.zIndex(isFocused ? 1 : -1)` modifier to the Button of ListElement. But you also have to store the focused state in a global place since - i guess - if one list element is focused we should remove the focus from the previously focused element (if any).

So the code would look like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var focusedIndex: Int?

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      Text("Some other views here that should also be covered")
      VStack {
        ForEach(0..<8) { i in
          ListElement(
            isFocused: focusedIndex == i,
            action: { focusedIndex = i }
          )
          .padding(.horizontal)
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

struct ListElement: View {
  let isFocused: Bool
  let action: () -> Void

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      action()
    }, label: {
      Text(isFocused ? "I am focused" : "I am not focused")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(.gray)
        .background(
          isFocused ?
          Color.pink
            .opacity(0.5)
            .frame(width: 10000, height: 10000)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
          : nil
        )

    })
    .zIndex(isFocused ? 1 : -1)
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

While it works I was not completely happy about this solution. I feel it hacky and I have no 100% confidence that it will work in every scenario.

So I think a better solution would be draw a "cover" above our full content and cut a hole to a specific position to make a part of the screen visible. To achieve this we have to determine the exact position of a given element in the screen and then we have to draw our cover and using "reversemask" to cut a hole in that position.
This solution has advantages such as it will work not only with list elements but any kind of view on the screen. We can also extend it to "cut" not rectangle but any shape of hole.

This solution has one more unsolved issue: if you have lots of elements, and lets say you scroll your content, then the hole position will be incorrect. You can solve it if you check your scrollview's contentOffset and substract scrollview's offset.x from the measured CGRect's origin.x.
I did not implement this because my code would be too complex with it, but you can easily extend this code using [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/observing-swiftui-scrollview-content-offset/) as a help.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var focusedRect: CGRect?
  @State var focusedIndex: Int?

  var body: some View {
    TutorialContent(
      highlightRect: focusedRect,
      action: {
        focusedRect = nil
        focusedIndex = nil
      },
      content: {
        ScrollView {
          VStack {
            VStack {
              Text("Another view which will be covered!")
            }
            ForEach(0 ..< 8) { i in
              let isFocused = i == focusedIndex
              ListElement(
                text: isFocused ? "I am focused" : "I am not focused",
                action: { rect in
                  focusedRect = rect
                  focusedIndex = i
                }
              )
              .padding(.horizontal)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    )
    .animation(.default, value: focusedIndex)
  }
}

struct ListElement: View {
  let text: String
  let action: (CGRect) -> Void

  @State var rect: CGRect = .zero

  var body: some View {
    Button(
      action: {
        action(rect)
      },
      label: {
        Text(text)
          .padding()
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .background(.gray)
      })
    .measure { rect = $0 }
  }
}

struct TutorialContent<Content: View>: View {
  let highlightRect: CGRect?
  let action: () -> Void
  let content: () -> Content

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if let rect = highlightRect {
        ZStack {
          Color.pink.opacity(0.5)
          Rectangle()
            .frame(
              width: rect.width,
              height: rect.height
            )
            .position(CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
            .blendMode(.destinationOut)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        .compositingGroup()
        .zIndex(highlightRect != nil ? 1 : -1)
        .onTapGesture {
          action()
        }
      }

      content()
    }
  }
}

extension View {
  @ViewBuilder func measure(
    in coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace = .global,
    _ block: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void
  ) -> some View {
    MeasuredView(coordinateSpace: coordinateSpace, onMeasure: block, content: self)
  }
}

struct MeasuredView<Content: View>: View {
  let coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace
  let onMeasure: (CGRect) -> Void
  let content: Content

  var body: some View {
    content
      .overlay {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
          Rectangle().fill(.clear)
            .task {
              onMeasure(proxy.frame(in: coordinateSpace))
            }
        }
      }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```